# How can I get the template and Python to communicate in Flask?

Tags: python, html, flask, web-development-server

For example, if I have the following code in index.html:

```
<div id='1'></div>
<div id='2'></div>
<div id='3'></div>
```

And, I have the following code in Python:

```
 from flask import *
 @app.route("/")
 def index():
     return render_template("index.html")

 @app.route('/experts')
 def route1():
     return render_template("experts.html", data=data)
```

So, among the three div blocks. When I click on any one of them. I want the program to know which one I click on, and pass the value of id (1,2,3) into the data variable in python so that I can use it on "expert.html".

What are some good ways I can achieve it? Thank you in advanced!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `divs`, you can use buttons. That way, `ajax` can be utilized in the front end to retrieve the id of the button clicked and pass it to the backend:

`"index.html"`:

```
<html>
 <body>
  <button id='1'>Button1</button>
  <button id='2'>Button2</button>
  <button id='3'>Button3</button>
</body>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
   $(document).ready(function() {
     $('button').click(function(event) {
       var the_id = event.target.id;
        $.ajax({
         url: "/get_id",
         type: "get",
         data: {the_id: the_id},
         success: function(response) {
           window.location.replace('/experts');
        },
        error: function(xhr) {
         //Do Something to handle error
        }
       });           
   });
 </script>
</html>
```

Then, a route to receive the id can be created, the results from the `ajax` can be stored in `flask.session`, and a "success" object can be passed back to the `ajax` in the `index.html` template. From the jquery in the template, the app can be redirected to `/expert`:

```
import flask
app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'SOME_SECRET_KEY'
@app.route('/get_id')
def expert():
  button_id = flask.request.args.get('the_id')
  flask.session['button_id'] = button_id
  return flask.jsonify({'success':True})

@app.route('/experts', methods=['GET'])
def experts():
  return render_template("experts.html", data=flask.session['button_id'])
```

Comment: Is there something that I need to import on the python ?

Comment: @ronnLee Nothing except `flask`.

Comment: Why do we store the result in "flask.session" and call "flask.jsonify"?

Comment: @ronnLee The result needs to be stored in `flask.session` so that the value can be persisted across the full duration of the user's time on the site (the session). `flask.jsonify` returns an object whose attributes can be accessed by the javascript.

Comment: Thanks again. Is there any restriction on how and what value we give to the secret key? I also tried to declare the secret key inside the function, but it did not work. Why does it have to be outside of the function?

Comment: @ronnLee This link provides a great explanation of secret keys in `flask`:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463939/demystify-flask-app-secret-key. Regarding the declaration of the secret key, in Python, functions have scoping  rules. Names assigned values inside a function/class's body are not accessible outside the scope of the function (the body of the function). When calling `app.route`, the interpreter searches for a variable `app` accessible in the current scope of the program, and in this example, it is the global scope.

Comment: I do know about the global and local scope of variables in python. However, if I declare the app.secretkey inside the expert() function, it will still crash in flask.session['button_id'] = button_id even though they're both inside a same function. Is that because flask.session is global, so the app.secretkey must also be global?

Comment: @ronnLee Yes, that is the case. My understanding is that `secretkey` must be bound to `app` before routes are added. `app.secret_key' must be placed before the routes are declared, after the import statements. Please see my recent edit.