# Difference between Flask sessions and JSON Web Tokens

Tags: jwt, authorization, token, session-cookies, flask-session

Flask session is nothing but a signed cookie which stored in the client-side. By looking at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463939/demystify-flask-app-secret-key` I feel like flask sessions can work without storing them anywhere in the server. Is that the case?

If so, can someone explain the fundamental difference between Flask sessions and JWT?