# Is SECRET_KEY necessary for Flask apps that use JWTs?

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-login, flask-jwt-extended

I'm writing a Python 3.8 Flask app that uses the `flask_jwt_extended` library for authentication. In most vanilla Flask tutorials, I've seen `app.config['SECRET_KEY] = [...]` get set at runtime. Details on [SECRET_KEY here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463939/demystify-flask-app-secret-key).

However, I'm now using `flask_jwt_extended` for authentication, as opposed to the vanilla `flask_login` library. In [code examples](https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/automatic_user_loading/) for `flask_jwt_extended`, I don't see `SECRET_KEY` getting set. Rather, a `JWT_SECRET_KEY` gets set.

My question: is `SECRET_KEY` only for session cookies, and therefore is it not necessary when I don't use `flask_login`? For an app using JWTs, do I only need to set the `JWT_SECRET_KEY`?

Comment: There is a mystery around this, sort of. But if you are using Flask-Sessions, you would have to define a secret key. Not the case if you are not using the sessions.

Comment: According to Flask-JWT-Extended docs `SECRET_KEY` is used for JWTs instead if `JWT_SECRET_KEY` is not defined. Docs: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/stable/options/#JWT_SECRET_KEY